# How to connect VSCode to GCP instances

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, vscode-remote

I am trying to connect VSCode to my GCP instances but am unable to. From a terminal, I can ssh into the machines with `gcloud compute ssh my_machine_name` but I'm not sure how to translate that into what VSCode Remote-SSH is looking for. When I created the config in VSCode I did this:

```
Host my_machine_name
    HostName my_machine_name
    User me@my_company.com
```

But the HostName is wrong because it's just the name of the machine and not the full HostName or IP address. I haven't even told VSCode that it's a GCP instance. How do I find the HostName? I imagine there's a connection between `my_machine_name` and the true HostName somewhere in my configs, but I can't find it. I found a GCP-Service.json file with the following keys:

```
{
  "type": 
  "project_id": 
  "private_key_id": 
  "private_key": 
  "client_email": 
  "client_id": 
  "auth_uri": 
  "token_uri": 
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
  "client_x509_cert_url": 
}
```

but I don't see anything that looks like a HostName or IP address.

Just to see, I tried to connect and got the following error:

```
Could not establish connection to "my_machine_name": Permission denied (publickey).
```

(Note sure if this is relevant but sometimes when I first try to connect I get the following, but after I click "Retry" it goes back to the publickey message again):

```
"Could not establish connection to "my_machine_name": Remote host key has changed, port forwarding is disabled."
```

So I tried to add a private key like so:

```
Host my_machine
    HostName my_machine
    User user@my_company.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I also tried the private key from my GCP-Service.json file as well but got the same result. What am I supposed to do to connect VSCode to my GCP instance?

Comment: Have a look at the following. I wrote it when using Cloud Shell but the same principles apply. If you're unable to get it to work, I'll have a look tomorrow: https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/200917/

Comment: Ensure OSLoging is disabled. See Voy answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/641453/unable-to-ssh-to-gce-permission-denied-publickey/1014949#1014949

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per my comment, this is straightforward and worked for me.

Assuming:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
INSTANCE=[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
ZONE=[[YOUR-ZONE]]
```

This is slightly hacky but either:

```sh
USER=$(\
  gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --command "whoami") && echo ${USER}
```

Or:

```sh
gcloud auth list --format="value(account)"
[[USER]]@[[DOMAIN]]
```

And:

```sh
IP=$(\
  gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format='value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)') && echo ${IP}
```

> **NOTE** the above assumes a single network interface and a public IP

Then, replacing the values with the above:

```
Host compute_engine
    HostName [[IP]]
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    User [[USER]]
    Port 22
```

Comment: I tried this approach although I must have misunderstood a step because I wasn't able to get it to work. I edited my question with what I tried.

Comment: You need to replace `IP` and `USER` with the actual values for your account and VM using the commands I showed

Comment: For me it was actually `gcloud compute instances describe "$INSTANCE" --zone "$ZONE" --project "$PROJECT" --format='value(networkInterfaces.networkIP)'`

Answer (score 54):

Simply running `gcloud compute config-ssh`, and you would get `example-instance.us-central1-a.MY-PROJECT` in your vs code ssh targets. Details at [config-ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh)

Comment: This is IMHO the better answer

Comment: Sorry complete noob here - can you explain step by step

Comment: @Tariq read this https://learn.canceridc.dev/cookbook/virtual-machines/using-vs-code-with-gcp-vms

Comment: this is awesome, you can check and run 

`gcloud compute config-ssh` --project <MY PROJECT> and simply `cat ~/.ssh/config` to see all your configs listed, it might be relevant to actually cat this into another file and define it and then inherit than overwhelm your config file

Comment: Wonderful answer. Someone should made a video on it

Comment: That would be a perfect answer if your instances have public IP; otherwise it does not do anything with `WARNING: No host aliases were added to your SSH configs because instances have no public IP.` @Martin's Wang response down below is then the solution.

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to use `gcloud beta compute start-iap-tunnel INSTANCE_NAME 22 --listen-on-stdin` to tunnel ssh access. (even without public ip)

[gcloud iap tunnel docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/start-iap-tunnel)

Your ssh config file:

```
Host YOUR_SERVER_NAME
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    User YOUR_USERNAME
    HostName YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME
    ProxyCommand gcloud beta compute start-iap-tunnel %h 22 --listen-on-stdin
```

Note:
If you are running vscode client on windows, you may need to have something like this

```
ProxyCommand powershell -Command "gcloud beta compute start-iap-tunnel %h 22 --listen-on-stdin"
```

You can always test your ssh connection with `ssh YOUR_SERVER_NAME -vvv`, (and see if ProxyCommand works or not).

---

I have this in https://github.com/martinwang2002/gcp-vscode-server with start on ssh connection and stop if inactive feature.

Answer (score 3):

If you already init gcloud successfully then you just need to type

`gcloud compute config-ssh`

Now you can access it with `ssh HOSTNAME` & it is also visible on your `remote ssh` vs code plugin. From your vs code, you can assess with `ctrl+shift+p` & `connect to host` and choose the host where you want to connect